# Windows Phone - Alternative to ViewportControl for UWP

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I'm looking to migrate my WP8.1 Silverlight App to Windows 10. For viewing images I used [ViewportControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.primitives.viewportcontrol(v=vs.105).aspx). This was a useful control for my app since an image could take up say 50% of the screen, then the user could pinch & zoom and the image would take up the whole screen.

[image: ViewportControl, Pinch & Zoom]

This control isn't available in UWP, and the only alternative I've come across is to place the image inside a [ScrollViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.aspx) control. However, this doesn't enlarge the image, it just zooms in on it. Does anyone know of an alternative to ViewportControl, or an easy way to replicate the behaviour of ViewportControl?

Comment: Maybe [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox) will help?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried Viewbox, played around with it a bit, but it doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.

Comment: @kernanb did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No. I've just been polishing the Sliverlight App for Windows 10 Mobile. It's working fine more or less, so there's no major reason to port the app right now. I'm focused on porting the PC version of the app to UWP though.

Comment: Hi @kernanb, did you get any solution for this. I'am also facing the same kind of issue to pinch and zoom in windows 10 UWP. Is there a way to achieve that without scrollviewer?

Comment: Hi Bhanuprakash. I never did. I still have the app as an older Silverlight app and haven't upgraded the app.